# How to know 'At what time app is being used' using Firebase Analytics

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am using firebase analytics in my app for analysis. But, I am not getting how to know the time interval in a day at which time app is being used more or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can log custom event with an "hour" as a property.

Don't forget to use `DateComponentsFormatter` to find local time rather than extracting UTC date.